# Earnest Fibber weapon details?

Tags: borderlands-2

I just recently completed the missions with the robot that wants to be human. At the end of the last one he gave me a pistol called the "Earnest Fibber". It's weapon details are not really very clear at all. It says that it does +3,000% damage, which at first I thought was a joke, but upon using it, realized that it is actually extremely powerful. My question is, what exactly does this gun do when you shoot it? How many bullets does it shoot at once and does it have any elemental effects or anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I could dig up on the wiki:

> **Would I lie to you?** – Fibber: Inaccurate stats displayed. Flavor stats +50% love, +3000% damage. Actual behavior is highly variable - may fire one projectile or several; shots may ricochet; if they do, ricochet hits may do substantially increased bonus damage - but will be constant for any given instance of the weapon. (Quest reward from Mal in Eridium Blight)

[Special Weapon Effects (Borderlands Wiki)](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Special_Weapon_Effects_Borderlands_2)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately that list doesn't tell us what the 50% love does.  But yes the weapon does tragic damage, not too accurate but sexy damage.

Comment: Now you are just trolling about the gun that lies to you.

Answer (score -1):

I had one that gave all my guns unlimited ammo clips so I never had to reload, just as long as the fibber was in my backpack. I think thats what 50% love applies to. It only lasted a short while though.

Comment: The 50% love probably does nothing. It is a gun that lies to you. The gun also has random stats. That is where the unlimited ammo came from, probably. Or you got the mod that regenerated ammo. This question is not the place to list all the random stats and abilities the gun might have.

Comment: Either he was a Gunzerker with the ammo class mod regen, or he had the Infinity pistol which grants infinite ammo.